# What bathroom vents/ceiling/roof vents and fans are most recommended?

Tags: vent, exhaust-fan

I need to vent a room in an uninsulated cabin - the ceiling is also the roof - so I don't need soffit tubing or anything like that.  I am looking for a fairly cheap item that has a large cfm ability.

(This is for venting steam from a maple syrup evaporator)

EDIT

We ended up just putting in two vents in the roof.  (Maybe 12"x12" each - though maybe a little smaller than that)

We did not need a fan.  We still get a tiny  bit of condensation on the ceiling but not even close to what it was before.  We are happy with the two vents but may add one more.

First we put in one vent and it was FAR superior to just having windows open.  We could actually see across the room when boiling/evaporating.  Then we put in a second vent and that made a difference too.

The next vent will be fed directly from a steam hood we will put over the evaporating pan.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a powered attic vent that would install directly into the roof.

But, It might be cheaper to get a bathroom vent, suspend it from the ceiling (like a garage door opener) and run a 3 or 4 inch pipe out under the eaves.

What are you using the cabin for the rest of the year?

Comment: The "cabin" is really just a huge shed at this point.  It is not habitable - we use it to store kayaks and tools, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A [wall-mountable bathroom fan](http://www.google.com/search?q=wall-mountable+bathroom+fan) would work.  Here's [one](http://www.pureairproducts.com/wallmountedutilityfans-akewf.htm) that's fairly cheap, with 180 CFM, and vents directly to the outside.

Another cheap option, if you have a window in the room would be to put in box fan in the opening to pull out the moist air.  If you have two windows, you could have one pulling moist air and the other blowing in outside air.

Comment: If it is like every sugar shack I've seen in Maine, they are an open draft ready to happen!!!  lol   Maybe two box fans in windows both blowing out. But maybe there are no windows, so cut a hole and fit a fan or two in the wall.  The doors and other windows will let in plenty of air. Never seen a shack with weather stripping.   Almost sap running time here. Can't wait for some cook down parties at my neighbor's.

Comment: Window fan may work - they are a little low though.  This is not a sugar shack - it is a run-down cabin/shack that will be demolished eventually - but it does not have the cupola that is traditional in sugar houses.  We boiled sap last weekend and after 6 hours the steam was all condensed on the ceiling and dripping on us.  The room was very steamy - could not see across a 12 foot room at head height.

Comment: cut some big windows up high on the walls and use a slab of old plywood to cover the hole when your not cooking.